Harris, direct limit is isomorphic to ring of germs
I have some question about this thing here :
One further object we should introduce here is the local ring of an affine variety
X at a point p $\in$ X, denoted $O_{X, p}$. This is defined to be the ring of germs of functions
defined in some neighborhood of p and regular at p. This is the direct limit of the
rings A($U_f$) = A(X)[l/f] where f ranges over all regular functions on X nonzero
at p, or in other words the localization of the ring A(X) with respect to the maximal
ideal $\mathfrak{m}_p$. Note that if Y $\subset$ X is an open set containing p then $O_{X,p} = O_{Y,p}$
I'm not quite sure, why it is direct limit of those rings, cause I can't construct an explicit isomorphism from $\lim \limits_{\rightarrow}A(X)[1/f]$ to $O_{X,p}$.
if $\phi_{ik}(h_i) = \phi_{jk}(h_j)$ then it's looks like in definition of equivalence relation on rings of germs. But as I said, I'm not quety sure, how to build an isomorphy
Another idea was that we need to define $\phi_{ij}$, but how?

Use the universal property of the direct limit.
